# Memory issue with server - when processing an excel sheet using Java

Tags: java, linux

I try to process 10 excel sheet each contains 50000 records(4.00MB each) using 4 threads. When am starting my available space in home is 80% . I start to process the file last night and when i check thattoday morning the process is stopped and its not completed. I don't write the nohup to null but i remove that file immediately after starting the server. Morning the sever space was 100% (Using df -h command).When i kill my application and check the space at that time its 82%. Am not getting the reason for this. Logs am generating in another partition using log4j.my total server space is around 30GB and also other application running in that.More that 4 JBOSS is running in that in total. I expect your help friends...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove the file, the file is not gone yet, it is just that it has no name anymore. The space can only be reclaimed when the last process closes the file.
(This happens also when you kill the process.)